# Excel Macro VBA Connection to Reflection Desktop to open a new Session

Tags: excel, vba, reflection

Im trying to automate a process in Reflection and am using the code from the attachmate site to open the connection:

```
Private Sub OpenReflectionIBMSession()
    'Declare an object variable for the Reflection application
    Dim app As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject
    
    'Declare frame, terminal, and view object variables:
    Dim frame As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.frame
    Dim terminal As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts.IbmTerminal
    Dim view As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.view
 
    'If an instance of Reflection is open, get a handle to it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set app = GetObject("Reflection Workspace")

    'Otherwise, create a new instance of Reflection
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(app) Or (app Is Nothing) Then
       Set app = New Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject
    End If
   
    With app
        'wait until Reflection initalizes
        Do While .IsInitialized = False
           .Wait 200
        Loop
       
       'Get a handle to the Frame object
        Set frame = .GetObject("Frame")
       
        'Make the frame visible so we can view the workspace
        frame.Visible = True
    End With
     
    'Create an Ibm3270 control using an .rd3x session document file
    Set terminal = app.CreateControl(Environ$("USERPROFILE") & _
    "\Documents\Micro Focus\Reflection\" & "mySavedSession.rd3x") 

    'Create a view so that we can display the session
    Set view = frame.CreateView(terminal)
End Sub
```

When the execution reaches the line

```
Set terminal = app.CreateControl(Environ$("USERPROFILE") & _
    "\Documents\Micro Focus\Reflection\" & "mySavedSession.rd3x")
```

I get a runtime error saying

`Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created`

Any idea why this might be happening ? I tried everything and nothing seems to work.
I get the same error when trying to create a new connection as well

Comment: `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` are .NET methods. The error is coming from your Reflection app object. You will need to check the API to see if you are missing a step before the `CreateControl` step.

Comment: I found this article and it looks like you are following the documentation correctly. You might be better off reaching out to their support because the error is in their code. https://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/16-1/vba-prog-guide/#get-screen-data-with-excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I found the solution. You need to activate the Attachmate and Reflection libraries in VBA before running it by going to Tools>References.